# php fedex set signature Label ADULT

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, fedex

I am working on wordpress site and using woocommerce extension http://www.woothemes.com/products/fedex-shipping-module/

**I am Passing the values Signature value to adults. But it is not working**

Please correct me where i am wrong

```
$request['RequestedShipment']['RateRequestTypes'] = $this->request_type;
$request['RequestedShipment']['PackageDetail'] = 'INDIVIDUAL_PACKAGES';
$request['RequestedShipment']['SpecialServicesRequested'][] = array(
    'SpecialServiceTypes' => 'SIGNATURE_OPTION',
    'SignatureOptionDetail' => array(
            'OptionType' => 'ADULT'
    )
);
```

`

Do i need to change something from the from the **RateService_v13.wsdl** file

Please suggest

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I resolved this issue

For further user having the same issue can resolve this by below code

```
$item['SpecialServicesRequested'] = array(
                    'SpecialServiceTypes' => 'SIGNATURE_OPTION',
                    'SignatureOptionDetail' => array(
                        'OptionType' => 'ADULT'
                         )
                    ); 
$request['RequestedShipment']['RequestedPackageLineItems'][] = $item;
```

Comment: Where did you place this code? I have added it to includes/class-wc-shipping-fedex.php and I'm not seeing any results at all.

Also, where does the feature appear after you successfully enable the signature option?

Comment: @Aaron Baxter This will result in having a surcharge applied in the response.  I've been scratching my head to know why the surcharge wasn't showing and I was missing the SpecialServiceTypes property.  Bad API design because no errors were reported.  LOL 7.5 years and still helpful.  StackOverflow is great.

Answer (score 0):

If Suppose anyone is using Fedex Integration with Laravel you may use below code.

In place of _DIRECT you may use _ADULT or any other option.

```
$packageLineItem1 = new FedexShipServiceCT\RequestedPackageLineItem();
$packageLineItem1
    ->setSequenceNumber(1)
    ->setItemDescription('Product')
    ->setSpecialServicesRequested(new FedexShipServiceCT\PackageSpecialServicesRequested(array(
        'SignatureOptionDetail' => new FedexShipServiceCT\SignatureOptionDetail(array(
            'OptionType' => FedexShipServiceST\SignatureOptionType::_DIRECT
        ))
    )))
    ->setDimensions(new FedexShipServiceCT\Dimensions(array(
        'Width' => 1,
        'Height' => 1,
        'Length' => 1,
        'Units' => FedexShipServiceST\LinearUnits::_IN
    )))
    ->setWeight(new FedexShipServiceCT\Weight(array(
        'Value' => 1,
        'Units' => FedexShipServiceST\WeightUnits::_LB
    )));
```

Thanks