# Wordpress WooCommerce FedEx Plugin Adult Shipping

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, fedex

I am trying to set the adult signature on the FedEx Plugin for Woocommerce. I have tried the code another question posted here: [php fedex set signature Label ADULT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23311732/php-fedex-set-signature-label-adult?answertab=votes#tab-top)

They said that they resolved the issue with this coding

```
$item['SpecialServicesRequested'] = array(
                'SpecialServiceTypes' => 'SIGNATURE_OPTION',
                'SignatureOptionDetail' => array(
                    'OptionType' => 'ADULT'
                     )
                ); 
$request['RequestedShipment']['RequestedPackageLineItems'][] = $item;
```

But I don't know why it ins't working. I am not 100% sure where to put this code but when I add it to the `woocommerce-shipping-fedex/shipping-fedex.php` it doesn't do anything.

Any Ideas?

To see this in progress go to christinagriffis.com/landonstaging

Answer (score 0):

Thanks...I'm not sure, but just try this below one. U will find  the addSpecialServices() function in shipwebseriviceclient.php5 page.[this is  FedEx Shipping integration library file ].

```
function addSpecialServices(){
$specialServices = array(
'SpecialServiceTypes' => array('COD'),
'CodDetail' => array(
'CodCollectionAmount' => array('Currency'                         =>   'USD', 'Amount' => 150),
  'CollectionType' => 'ANY')// ANY.                                                 
GUARANTEED_FUNDS
  );
return $specialServices; 
}
```